# Object's data missing when passing to Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, meteor, reactjs

In my React/Meteor application, I am trying to pass an object with data from the state to a method on the server, for insertion into the database. However, there seems to be an issue passing the object from the React component to the Meteor method - one of the child objects ends up in the Meteor method, but all of its children are gone. I do nothing to the object except use `check()` to ensure it is an `Object`:

```
'Appointments.saveData'(dataObj) {
   check(dataObj, Object);

   console.log(dataObj);

   // ....
 }
```

Here's what happens on the front-end:

```
Meteor.call('Appointments.saveData', {
  vitalsData: this.state.vitalsData || {},
  subjectiveData: this.state.subjectiveData || '',
  physicalExamData: this.state.physicalExamData || {},
  rosData: this.state.rosData || {},
  impressionData: this.state.impressionData || [],
  extraNotes: this.state.extraNotes || ''
}, (err, res) => {
  if (res && !err) {
    this.refs.toasts.success(
      'Data for this encounter has been saved.',
      'Records saved!'
    );
  } else {
    this.refs.toasts.error(
      'An unknown error has occurred. Reload the page and try again.',
      'Error!'
    );
  }
});
```

I combine all of my state variables into an object using `{}`, which in turn becomes `dataObj` in the method. However, `dataObj.impressionData` exists, and is an array containing objects, however, data is missing from any of the objects in the array.

For example, `dataObj.impressionData[0].diagnosis` should be an object, in fact, it is supposed to be an exact copy of an object already pulled from the database. However, if I `console.log` it, the object is empty.

I have verified that the data exists as it should at each step before passing to the Meteor method. I `console.log` the object immediately before calling `Meteor.call` and immediately after calling `check` in my method. I cannot for the life of me understand why data is missing.

What am I forgetting?

**EDIT:** I've changed my code so that the data is now added to the state directly from a `ref`. Now the server method does properly receive the object. However, in the following code:

```
if (dataObj.impressionData && dataObj.impressionData.length > 0) {
      dataObj.impressionData.forEach(obj => {
        console.log(obj); // obj.diagnosis exists and is as expected
        const x = ICD10Codes.findOne({ _id: obj.diagnosis._id });
        console.log(x); // this also works as it should
        impressionFields.push({ patientId: appt.patient._id, diagnosis: x, note: obj.note, x });
      });
    }
```

Setting diagnosis to `x`, which I *KNOW* is a valid copy of the object straight from the database yields the same results:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.EncounterData.findOne()
...
    "impression" : {
        "patientId" : "47de32b428d8c4aaac284af3",
        "appointmentId" : "TwL7DF9FoXPRgmrjR",
        "fields" : [
            {
                "patientId" : "47de32b428d8c4aaac284af3",
                "diagnosis" : {

                }
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

I think I'm going crazy.

Comment: Are you sure `this` is actually pointing to your React component? Where are you calling the Meteor code?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes - I actually `console.log(this.state.impressionData)` immediately before the `Meteor.call` and the data is fine there. It is a function in the React component that is called after a 'save' button is pressed and data from child components is stored.

Comment: Can you show us the function and the save? I'm thinking your issue might be because state isn't set yet. Remember that `this.setState` is an **asynchronous** call, so you have to use the lifecycle methods to ensure it's call has finished.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Here's the relevant portion: 
    `case 'impression':
        this.setState({ impressionData: data }, this.callServerMethod);
        break;`
`this.callServerMethod` is the code in the post where I call `Meteor.call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself - it turns out that I was importing my SimpleSchema objects as default but exporting my SimpleSchema objects as named. The SimpleSchema objects were thus invalid.

Answer (score 0):

So your issue comes down to the fact that [`this.setState` is an **asynchronous** function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate), so when you make your Meteor call, `this.state` hasn't actually be updated yet. As such, you need to wait for the `this.setState` call to finish. The only way to do this is to use the [React lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods). You can use either `componentWillUpdate` (called before the next render) or `componentDidUpdate` (called after the next render).

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    save: function() {
        ...
        case 'impression': 
            this.setState({ impressionData: data }, this.callServerMetho‌​d);  
            break;
        ...
    },

    // This is one of the React lifecycle methods
    componentWillUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
        // Put your Meteor call here
        // Make sure to use nextState instead of this.state
        // This way you know that this.state has finished updating
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue - [here's](https://lambda.sx/ODr.png) a screenshot of what the console shows. The first `[Object]` is what `nextState` (and, previously, `this.state`) has for `impressionData`. The second is what the Meteor method receives. What's missing here is the content of the diagnosis object. Everything else is fine, including other nested objects.